# Auto sum HTML table Column like we always do in Excel

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have one page which have one html table and the last column of the table has  numeric value .

My doubt is , when we fill some numeric values in Excel column and If we select those columns together it will tell the sum of the total columns .

I want to do the same in HTML Table column. Is this possible to do ?

If It is possible can someone help me in this?

Can Someone help me how to do this... I googled everywhere I don't know how to do..

Comment: Yes is very possible

Comment: @charlietfl can you guide me? I don't know how to start...

Comment: Where is your actual problem? Detecting data change? Getting data from the cells? Converting from string to number? Summing the data? Returning the value to a cell? Creating a cell or row? Please be specific with your problem. Do not present a specification and expect fully developed code as a result. Please read the [tour] and read the [help] to get a better understanding on writing an appropriate question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @JonP I don't  know the skeleton or how to start .

Answer (score 2):

Get the last column cells, extract the number, sum.

```js
const sum = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td:last-of-type')).
    map(x => parseFloat(x.textContent)).reduce((x, y) => x + y);
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Extremely sorry for the late reply , I am new to this, can u tell me how you will indicate the particular tables last column

Comment: Just adjust the selector. I can't tell you more specifically unless you tell me how to find your table (you have no HTML in your question, nor the CSS selector for the table)